# Most efficient way to delete database data in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework-4

For integration testing I need to wipe all data information in a database.
I'm using Entity Framework 4
What's the most efficient way?
Would be nice if I don't need to specify table or class names every time I add a new class to the model.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most efficient way to delete database data is to drop all tables and recreate all tables.

Comment: actually, most efficient is Truncating all tables, but requires a specific order

Comment: truncating can be time consuming because of the cascades

Comment: So, I shoud use a sql statement for droping the database and then recreate it?

Comment: If you have sql script for creating database schema, you can just add dropping before this script. Or just create script for truncating and then no need to recreate database.

Comment: I resolve it using scripts with ExecuteStoreCommand from EF4 context object

Comment: In a project with EF4 Model First I'm using container.DeleteDabase() and container.CreateDatabase() and works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the fastest, but it is the simplest.  It even clears your connection pool:

```
using (var context = new DataContext())
{
    context.Database.Delete();
}
```